# Install the same file to multiple destination folders in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to define more than one destination folder in Inno Setup script?

example:

```
Source: "Test.exe"; DestDir: "{app}" // here I need a second folder
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not add the file twice with differen `DestDir`s? Haven't tried, but should work. Otherwise it's hard to make a suggestion without knowing what exactly you're trying to achieve. There might be better ways, if only we knew what you're trying to do :-)